# Ant Velocity antiderivative word problem

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve the following question by getting my variables, etc mixed up.

F for velosity of an ant walking along a shelf is:
$$
v(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
5 t, & 0 \leq t<1 \\
6 \sqrt{t}, & 1 \leq t \leq 2
\end{array}\right.
$$

$t=sec, v=cm/s$.  Estimate time for ant to get to 4cm from Start Pos.

So what I have is
$$
t=0,\ v(0)=5t, \ s(0)=0\\
t=n,\ v(n)=6\sqrt{t} , \ s(n)=4
$$
For S pos,

$$
v=5t\\
s=5/2t^2 ( c=0 \ at \ s(0)=0)\\
s(1)=5/2(1)^2 = 2.5cm \ @ \ t=1sec
$$

At E pos,
$$
v(n)=6 \sqrt{t}\\
s(n)=4t^{3/2} \\
s(2)=4(2)^{3/2}+c=4cm \rightarrow c\approx-7.3137
$$

So, for 1.5cm

$$
s(n)=4t^{3/2}-7.3137=1.5\\
s(n)=4t^{3/2}=1.5+7.3137\\
s(n)=t^{3/2}=8.8137/4\ \rightarrow t\approx3.27
$$
So time to travel 4 cm = 1+3.27 = 4.27 seconds.

I know the answer is wrong but where have I made my mistakes?
Thanks.

Comment: How far did the ant walk in the first second? What is the total distance travelled by $t=1.5$?

Comment: I had s(1)=5/2(1)^2 - so 2.5cm in the first sec 1sec.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why $ s(2) = 4(2)^(3/2) +c = 4cm$? In particular, why the second equality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$s(n)=4(t)^{3/2}+c, \,$ for $(1 \le t \le 2)$

At $t = 1$, ant is at $2.5$ cm. So, $c = 2.5 - 4 = -1.5$

$4 = 4(t)^{3/2} - 1.5 \implies t \approx 1.2365$

Comment: When I calculate 4=4(t)3/2−1.5, I get t=2.07sec. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Do you get $t^{3/2} = 5.5 / 4 = 1.375$? From there $t = (1.375)^{2/3}$.

Comment: @user41592 did you get it now?

Comment: Made 2 algebraic mistakes. One being t=(1.375)^3/2. Fixed and got 1.2365. So - 2.5=1 sec and 1.5cm = 1.2365 ⟹ 2.2365?

Comment: @user41592 No, the total time is $1.2365$. As at $t = 1$, you are already at $2.5$ cm. You are finding time when you are at $4$ cm.

Answer (score 0):

Let $T$ be the time for the ant to travel 4cm. Then, integrate over the velocity to get the distance equation below

$$4= \int_0^T v(t)dt= \int_0^1 5t dt +\int_1^T 6\sqrt tdt = \frac52 + 4(T^{3/2}-1)
$$
Solve to obtain $T= \frac14 \sqrt[3]{121}$.